# Не импортируется функция ifconfig или tar из библиотеки sh

Tags: python, python-3.x, sh

Доброго времени суток!

`from sh import ifconfig, tar` - не импортируются функции.

Библиотека `sh` скачана:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сама библиотека импортируется:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собираюсь изучить эту библиотеку для проекта. В статьях видел как разработчики импортируют эти функции из библиотеки `sh`.

Что делать? Подскажите. Или все таки дело в версии языка? Видел на сайте Pypi, что библиотека `sh` работает до версии python3.8.

Comment: Насколько я понял, в сам модуль `sh` не встроено ничего, он просто вызывает доступные команды операционной системы. Из того же каталога из которого вы запускаете скрипт можно запустить из командной строки `ifconfig`? Может он в путях не прописан или прав на него нет. Попробуйте начать с `sh.ls()` и `sh.pwd()` проверку работы модуля.

Comment: Какую среду разработки используете? Если PyCharm, то проверьте, что для проекта указан системный интерпретатор, а не виртуальное окружение. Либо установите библиотеку в виртуальное окружение проекта.

Comment: Спасибо вам! Оказывается это так, в сам модуль ```sh``` ничего не встроено, и функции работают.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В комментариях ответили. В модуль `sh` ничего не встроено, но функции работать будут.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]